# iPython notebook not working behind VPN

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vpn

I'm running iPython notebook on my local computer. However, because I am in China, I need to use a VPN (specifically Astrill's OpenWeb protocol) to access most of the internet. On one of my PCs, iPython notebook won't run properly when the VPN is running. For example, when opening my homepage: `http://localhost:8888/tree`, I see the error message:

```
Astrill Error
Connection Closed Gracefully
```

iPython notebook also won't let me open or save workbooks if the VPN is running. Any idea why and how I can fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem 4 years later. Try replacing "http://localhost:8888/tree" with 127.0.0.1:8888/tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `localhost` to your VPN whitelist. So that the corresponding requests would not be passed to the proxy. If this still does not work, check if you are using global mode of your VPN which might overlook the whitelist config.

> whitelist means an address list of direct access, which your VPN would not transfer the corresponding traffic to the proxy address.

Comment: For me, the solution was to add the port rather than localhost as a whole. I'm using Nordvpn and
`nordvpn whitelist add port 8888`
solved the problem for me.